# RIGHT function to get the last three characters

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I'm using the following formula in a validation rule:

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Level_Name__c ,"Level"),
IF(CONTAINS(Name,"ONE")||
CONTAINS(Name,"TWO")
,TRUE, FALSE), FALSE)
```

How can I get the last three characters of the Name and compare with Level_Name__c except for the "Level" value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I get the last three characters of the Name

Use the Right function `RIGHT(text, num_chars)` - [documentation link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5)

`RIGHT(Name, 3)`

> and compare with Level_Name__c except for the "Level" value

It seems contradictory, when your `Level_Name__c` is "Level" it doesn't make sense to compare it with some value that is 3 characters long - the result will always be `false`.

If you still need to compare a picklist value with some text, then you need to use the `TEXT(value)` function.

And your formula would be:

```
IF(RIGHT(Name, 3) == TEXT(Level_Name__c), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Cheers, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

```
Contains(TEXT(Level_Name__c),RIGHT(name,3))
```